# SQL Server : how to select a fixed amount of rows (select every x-th value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

A short description: I have a table with data that is updated over a certain time period. Now the problem is, that - depending on the nature of the sensor which sends the data - in this time period there could be either 50 data sets or 50.000. As I want to visualize this data (using ASP.NET / c#), for a first preview I would like to SELECT just 1000 values from the table.

I already have an approach doing this: I count the rows in the time period of interest, with a simple "where" clause to specify the sensor-id, save it as a variable in SQL, and then divide the count() by 1000. I've tried it in MS Access, where it works just fine:

```
set @divider = select count(*) from table where [...]

SELECT (Int([RowNumber]/@divider)), First(Value)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY (Int([RowNumber]/@divider));
```

The trick in Access was, that I simply have a data field ("RowNumber"), which is my PK/ID, and goes from 0 up. I tried to accomplish that in SQL Server using the `ROW_NUMBER()` method, which works more or less. I've got the right syntax for the method, but I can not use the `GROUP BY` statement

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY
>   clauses.

meaning `ROW_NUMBER()` can't be in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Now I'm kinda stuck. I've tried to save the `ROW_NUMBER` value into a char or a separate column, and `GROUP BY` it later on, but I couldn't get it done. And somehow I start to think, that my strategy might have its weaknesses ...? :/

To clarify once more: I don't need to `SELECT TOP 1000` from my table, because this would just mean that I select the first 1000 values (depending on the sorting). I need to `SELECT` every x-th value, while I can compute the x (and I could even round it to an INT, if that would help to get it done). I hope I was able to describe the problem understandable ...

This is my first post here on StackOverflow, I hope I didn't forget anything essential or important, if you need any further information (table structure, my queries so far, ...) please don't hesitate to ask. Any help or hint is highly appreciated - thanks in advance! :)

---

Update: SOLUTION! Big thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven!!!

Here is how I did it in the end:

I declare 2 variables - I count my rows and SET it into the first var. Then I use ROUND() on the just assigned variable, and divide it by 1000 (because in the end I want ABOUT 1000 values!). I split this operation into 2 variables, because if I used the value from the COUNT function as basis for my ROUND operation, there were some mistakes.

```
declare @myvar decimal(10,2) 
declare @myvar2 decimal(10,2)

set @myvar = (select COUNT(*)
from value_table
where channelid=135 and myDate >= '2011-01-14 22:00:00.000' and myDate <= '2011-02-14 22:00:00.000'
)
```

set @myvar2 = ROUND(@myvar/1000, 0)

Now I have the rounded value, which I want to be my step-size (take every x-th value -> this is our "x" ;)) stored in @myvar2. Next I will subselect the data of the desired timespan and channel, and add the ROW_NUMBER() as column "rn", and finally add a WHERE-clause to the outer SELECT, where I divide the ROW_NUMBER through @myvar2 - when the modulus is 0, the row will be SELECTed.

```
select * from
(
select (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id desc)) as rn, myValue, myDate
from value_table
where channel_id=135 and myDate >= '2011-01-14 22:00:00.000' and myDate<= '2011-02-14 22:00:00.000'
) d
WHERE rn % @myvar2 = 0
```

Works like a charm - once again all my thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven, see the comment below for the original posting!

Comment: Can you provide some simplified data example and desired output?

Comment: Can you provide which version of SQL you are using?   It appears to be mySQL, but is in 2005, 2008, etc?

Comment: @Sparky - Actually, he does say MS SQL on the question, so SQL Server, and for the use of `ROW_NUMBER` it should be 2005+

Comment: Welcome! It is always a good idea to provide an example of the table structure with dummy data and the desired out put as well as explicitly state which RDBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc) and which version (2005, 2008, etc).

Comment: Hi all,

I use MS SQL 2008 (10.0.5500), and my table is absolutely simple:
ID(PK,INT) / Value(float) / Date(DateTime) / SensorID(FK, INT)
So the ID is just the PK of my values-table, and can't be used to identify my entries. Value is the field of real interest, and Date is - self explaining - the timestamp of the value entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In essence, all you need to do to select the x-th value is retain all rows where the modulus of the rownumber divided by x is 0.

```
WHERE rn % @x_thValues = 0
```

Now to be able to use your `ROW_NUMBER`'s result, you'll need to wrap the entire statement into in a subselect

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
                    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
            FROM    DummyData
        ) d
WHERE   rn % @x_thValues = 0
```

Combined with a variable to what x-th values you need, you might use something like this testscript

```
DECLARE @x_thValues INTEGER = 2

;WITH DummyData AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) v (Value))
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
                    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
            FROM    DummyData
        ) d
WHERE   rn % @x_thValues = 0
```

Comment: This is standard practice for using windowing functions. Inner query to get a result and outer query to filter.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick response, I will give it a shot tomorrow and let you know immediatly - looks promising! :)

Comment: Works like a charm - using the modulus in the WHERE-clause was the solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One more option to consider:

```
Select Top 1000 * 
From dbo.SomeTable 
Where ....
Order By NewID()
```

but to be honest- like the previous answer more than this one.
The question could be about performance..

Comment: @Janis - The problem with this is that the 1000th random records get selected. I don't think that was what OP intended. The resultset needs to be ordered and from that ordered set, the n-th value should be chosen.