# SQL Query issue

Tags: android, sqlite

Struggling to get SQL query to work since morning. I am trying to check if particular field has 0 value only for first 500 (Record 1 to Records 500) records.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM UnMappText  WHERE updateTime = '0' desc LIMIT 0, 500;
```

This gives me the below error:

```
Process: com.ylg.dbaccess, PID: 18738
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "desc": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM UnMappText WHERE updateTime = '0' desc LIMIT 0, 500
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
            at com.ylg.dbaccess.UnMappText (DBValue.java:3312)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

So I tried the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM UnMappText WHERE updateTime = '0' ORDER By updateTime LIMIT 0, 500;
```

This gives me a result but doesn't give result for first 500 records but just gives 500 records results.

Comment: hint: to order thing, you have to actually use the keyword `order by`. Also, you have to say what you want to order on.

Comment: @njzk2 that doesn't give me correct results. I have already tried it

Comment: what do you mean? you query code is wrong and cannot give any result, as evidenced by the exception.

Comment: @njzk2 I get results but not for first 500 records

Comment: no. you get an exception, not records.

Comment: @njzk2: I wanted to say I have tried orderBy but doesn't give me correct results. I have updated that in my question too.

Comment: I think you want something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777178/sql-server-how-to-select-a-fixed-amount-of-rows-select-every-x-th-value

Comment: your order by does not do anything, since all records returned by that query have an `updateTime` value of 0.

Comment: `How do I get to check updateTime has 0 for first 500 records?` I don't undestand what you mean. can you give examples? Do you want to select 500 records (the notion of `first`, you'll have to further explain according to what) and make sure that all times are 0?

Comment: @njzk2:I am trying to check if particular field has 0 value only for first 500 (Record 1 to Records 500) records.

Comment: I would do something like `updateTime = 0 and record between 1 and 500` (where `record` would be the column you use to figure the record number)

Comment: @njzk2 - That solves my issues. Thanks a lot. BETWEEN was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you must add the order by clause for make the "desc" to work:

```
SELECT * FROM UnMappText WHERE updateTime = '0' order by "field_name_to_order" desc LIMIT 0, 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a **reserved keyword**, and can't be used as a column name.

Use something like `description`, instead.

For your reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

---

Or you miss the `ORDER BY` clause before the `DESC` attribute

As in `... ORDER BY myField DESC ...`

Comment: what suggests you that `desc` is intended to be used as a column name, here?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check first 500 records without sorting on updateTime then try this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM UnMappText LIMIT 0,500) as t  WHERE t.updateTime = '0' ;
```

and if you want to sort then check first 500 records then try this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM UnMappText order by updateTime LIMIT 0,500) as t  WHERE t.updateTime = '0' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM UnMappText order by updateTime LIMIT 500) as t  WHERE t.updateTime = '0' ;
```